# How to handle start flatlist at determined index which items are different in height

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist which items height are different. (I am using auto-height image that in renderItem). From previous index an index is passed to flatList that this index is initialScrollIndex of flatList. I try to use scrollToIndex, first it take flatList to correct item, but after afew seconds it scrolled up. I think this is caused by different item height.
also I try scrollToOffset but it takes long time to calculate the index of item.
How to handle this issue?